# How to simulate login with Python Requests requiring Authentication Token

Tags: python, http, session, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to use Requests to login to this site, but it appears they employ a more complicated Authentication login. I don't have much knowledge in HTTP to understand what needs to be done. Appreciate some advise. I've screenshot the relevant information below. 
I recorded an actual login. 
[Login Post Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/horUc.png)
[Authentication Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDHj9.png) 
I do not understand the information in the Authentication Page.

My Code below was trying to follow the steps the actual site took.

```
import requests
theedge1 = 'https://auth.theedgemarkets.com/login.html?_pt_=MQ%3D%3D'
theedge_login = 'https://auth.theedgemarkets.com/api/login'
theedge2 = 'https://auth.theedgemarkets.com/dialog/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=theedgemarkets4209&redirect_uri=http://www.theedgemarkets.com/user-login?url=http://www.theedgemarkets.com/my&scope=offline_access'
theedge3 = 'http://www.theedgemarkets.com/user-login?url=http://www.theedgemarkets.com/my'
root_edge = 'http://www.theedgemarkets.com/my'
payload_edge = dict(username='username', password='password')
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.get(theedge1)
    s.post(theedge_login, data=payload_edge)
    s.get(theedge2, headers=dict(referer=theedge1))
    s.get(theedge3)
    response = s.get(root_edge)
```

Thanks and much appreciated.